# remove a string using jquery or css

Tags: jquery, css

I have some html:

```
    <span class="variantprice"><span class="pricelabel">
Preis&nbsp;</span>€ 240,00 (CHF)</span>
```

Whats the best way to remove the (CHF) using jquery? OR even CSS???

Comment: i don't think using span inside span is valid for html standarts, correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: A `span` is an in-line element, and can be contained by either block-level, or in-line, elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
    $(".variantprice").html(function(){
        return $(this).html().replace(" (CHF)", ""); 
    });
```

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AYZEs/